# Bash: Split a single line of output with spaces into multiple lines of one word each

Tags: string, bash, awk

I have a command which outputs a randomly ordered set on words. My goal is, ultimately, to get a sorted list.  I'm trying to find a way to do this that can be done with a single command.  I know that if the output is on multiple lines, it can be sorted by piping it to `sort`, such as

```
$ echo "foo
> bar
> baz" | sort
bar
baz
foo
```

So is there a simple command that I can use to split a string like `"foo bar baz"` into separate lines, so I can accomplish my goal with `echo "foo bar baz" | magic_string_splitter | sort`

edit: bonus, the list actually contains some extra output at the end that would be great to ignore.  so for instance, the output of my command might actually be like this

```
$ print_words
foo bar baz are your words
```

But I'd still like the final result to just be

```
bar
baz
foo
```

We can totally strip off and ignore the "are your words" at the end.

Comment: you can temporarily set `IFS` to a whitespace

Comment: According to which criteria can "are your words" be omitted?

Comment: @Cyrus they are always the last 3 words.  so no matter what the randomly output words are, the output will always end with the literal string `" are your words"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With GNU awk:

```
echo 'foo bar baz are your words' | awk '{NF-=3; OFS="\n"; $1=$1}1' | sort
```

> `NF-=3`: Remove last 3 columns from current row.
>
> `OFS="\n"`: set output field separator to newline (or use `OFS=ORS`).
>
> `$1=$1`: Forces awk to rebuild current row with new OFS (now newline).
>
> `1`: awk evaluates `1` as true expression and outputs the current line.

Output:

```
bar
baz
foo
```

---

See: [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – FS, OFS, RS, ORS, NR, NF, FILENAME, FNR](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/)

Comment: and with any awk: `echo '...' | awk '{for (i=1;i<=(NF-3);i++) print $i}' | sort'`

Answer (score 5):

You can use `tr` and (GNU) `head`:

```
$ echo "foo bar baz are your words" | tr -s '[:blank:]' '\n' | head -n -3 | sort
bar
baz
foo
```

- `tr -s '[:blank:]' '\n'` squeezes any runs of blanks and replaces them with one linebreak
- `head -n -3` drops the last three lines

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "foo bar   baz more" |tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 1-3 | fmt -w 1
```

The `cut` selectes the first three fields and the `fmt` arranges them into separate lines.